# How do you declare a named nested block parameter?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I currently have the following, which is working:

```
typedef BOOL(^InnerBlockType)(int arg1, int arg2);

- (BOOL)doStuff:(void(^)(InnerBlockType innerBlock))block;
```

But I would like to remove the typedef and make the block inline, so the arguments are visible after autocompleting, making it easier to use. I can't get the syntax right, though. I can get it 99% there, but not including giving the block a name. When I insert an identifier, Xcode tells me that it's expecting a `)`.

```
// Compiles, but is missing the inner block's name
- (BOOL)doStuff:(void(^)(BOOL(^)(int arg1, int arg2)))block;

// This is what I'd like
- (BOOL)doStuff:(void(^)(BOOL(^)(int arg1, int arg2))innerBlock)block;
// But I get a compiler error here:                  ^   Expected ')'
```

I've tried moving the `innerBlock` identifier in and out of all other different parenthesis combinations, but I get the same error. Where can I insert the `innerBlock` identifier that satisfies the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the name:

```
- (BOOL)doStuff:(void(^)(BOOL(^)(int arg1, int arg2)))block;
```

Or insert it like a traditionally named block:

```
- (BOOL)doStuff:(void(^)(BOOL(^innerBlock)(int arg1, int arg2)))block;
```

Although, I did notice autocomplete was giving me a rough time and it didn't seem to pick up on it very well.  Here was the result:

```
[self doStuff:^(BOOL (^innerBlockType)(int arg1, int arg2)) {
    //
}];
```

Comment: We were typing our answers at the same time! Some additional digging turned up the second one you provided. I deleted mine now. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, the autocomplete is funky. I reported it to Apple.